# Ignite heap not release, this is a memery leak?

Tags: java, heap-memory, ignite

I have a 20 minute pressure test during which the free JVM heap size drops from 97% to 3%. Even if I wait 5 hours, the amount of free space does not change. If I try to have a test again, the GC has too much work and causes a long JVM pause. I use 2.7 Ignite, I do not save data on tje heap, I save data with jdbcthin.
I thought that when my test is over, the JVM heap will realize, but it doesn't look like it.

I attached the JVM properties and the configuration below.

JVM property

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xms10g -Xmx10g -server"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/alidata/soft/ignite/heapdump -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Xloggc:/alidata/soft/ignite/gc/gc.log"
```

config properties

```xml
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <!-- Configure internal thread pool. -->
    <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="96"/>

    <!-- Configure system thread pool. -->
    <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="16"/>

    <!-- Configure query thread pool. -->
    <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="96"/>

    <property name="systemWorkerBlockedTimeout" value="#{60 * 60 * 1000}"/>

    <property name="failureHandler">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.failure.StopNodeFailureHandler"/>
    </property>
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
  <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
      <!-- Enable write throttling.-->
      <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
      <!-- Set concurrency level -->
      <property name="concurrencyLevel" value="4"/>

      <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
          <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
          <!-- Increasing the buffer size to 1 GB. -->
          <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize"
                    value="#{1 * 1024L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
          <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 4GB. -->
           <!-- 1 GB initial size. -->
          <property name="initialSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
          <property name="maxSize" value="#{8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

          <!-- Enabling RANDOM_2_LRU eviction for this region.  -->
            <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
        </bean>
      </property>
      <!-- Size of the WAL (Write Ahead Log) segment -->
      <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

      <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true" />

      <property name="walCompactionLevel" value="1" />

      <!-- Set the page size to 4 KB -->
      <property name="pageSize" value="#{4 * 1024}"/>
      <!--
          Sets a path to the root directory where data and indexes are
          to be persisted. It's assumed the directory is on a separated SSD.
      -->
      <property name="storagePath" value="/alidata/soft/ignite/persistence"/>

      <!--
          Sets a path to the directory where WAL is stored.
          It's assumed the directory is on a separated HDD.
      -->
      <property name="walPath" value="/alidata/soft/ignite/wal"/>

      <!--
          Sets a path to the directory where WAL archive is stored.
          The directory is on the same HDD as the WAL.
      -->
      <property name="walArchivePath" value="/alidata/soft/ignite/wal/"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
      <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
      <property name="ipFinder">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
          <property name="addresses">
            <list>
              <value>172.16.14.14:47500..47509</value>
              <value>172.16.14.15:47500..47509</value>
              <value>172.16.14.16:47500..47509</value>
              <value>172.16.14.17:47500..47509</value>
            </list>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
   </bean>
```

3% picture
[image: Console output showing the 3% free heap space stat]

Can you give me any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please include the output, not a picture of it, as some screens will not display the image well and it causes other accessibility issues.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the G1 garbage collector? It's much better for these kinds of workloads than the parallel GC you have configured.

Comment: G1 has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the heap is held by `ConnectionManager.usedConns`.

However, there are no released Apache Ignite versions which have `ConnectionManager` class. It's certainly not in 2.7.

If you are using some kind of your own builds from master branch, you're kind of on your own. Consider upgrading to the latest builds from `ignite-2.8` branch, this problem may be fixed there. The release is not there yet, but code is available and presumably more stable than whatever you are using.

Either way. You're not really running Apache Ignite and certainly not AI 2.7.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that I use gridgain-community-8.7.9, I change to gridgain-community-8.7.10, this question still exist. When  I change to apache-ignite-2.7.6, this question have solved.  This is a bug?

Comment: @zhangzl Is is not impossible. Can you post a minimal reproducer of this issue somewhere? Maybe on GridGain forums or even here.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite does not use too much heap, unless you happen to use on-heap caching.

Please make sure you're not retaining too much data on heap during your test.

I recommend gathering a heap dump, analyzing it with e.g. Eclipse MAT to see what happens there.

Comment: I'm sure not use on-heap cache. I have a command by jmap:  org.h2.table.Column's instance is very large

Comment: I have a question: I create table with QueryEntity, and I have update or query with JDBC. What's the impact?

Comment: I think that you execute requests that are too large, and/or forget to close ResultSet's.
Please also consider enabling lazy SQL (`lazy=false`)

Comment: I have a JDBC with JdbcTemplate or Mybatis, ResultSet should be closed. I can have a try with lazy SQL. But now the JVM heap not free up, I think that when the SQL finish, the JVM will free up.

Comment: Are you sure you're not pulling the whole cache contents with a single statement (such as doing `SELECT *` without `WHERE`)?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I only with some Join but have limit 20.Today, JVM heap not free up

Comment: Heap Usage:
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 9603317760 (9158.4375MB)
   used     = 9603298088 (9158.418739318848MB)
   free     = 19672 (0.01876068115234375MB)
   99.99979515412807% used

Comment: Maybe you are using statements that try to sort the whole result set without index, for example. It's hard to say. I recommend starting with the simplest possible queries, then adding features to find out the step where heap usage grows.

Comment: I have a simplest possible query, I find that when I have  a insert with jdbcTemplate, JVM heap increace very fast

Comment: That's very strange indeed, can you share some reports from MAT?

Comment: I have a MAT report: https://github.com/zhangzl0119/temp/blob/master/java_pid17544_Leak_Suspects.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have enouhg time to provide small reproducer please describe your pressure scenario. It is really important to investigate.
The most reason of huge counts of connection at the `ConnectionManager.usedConn` is not closed JDBC connection and query cursors (`QueryCursor`) at the native API.

AI 2.7 use ThreadLocal connections and has less potential leaks for simple cases.
We have had to change connection manager logic to perform "lazy" mode (to reduce heap usage for huge result sets).